# Plotting word frequency (line plot)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a list of words:

```
s=['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'date', 'banana', 'apple', 'orange',...]
```

and I computed their frequency:

```
pd.Series(s).value_counts()
```

I would like to plot now the frequency not as bar plot, but line plot:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: pd.Series(s).value_counts().plot.line() https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.line.html

Comment: `pd.Series(s).value_counts().plot()` works for me. Pandas v0.25.3, Matplotlib v3.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried this and got the desired output ! hope it helps !

```py
s=['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'date', 'banana', 'apple', 'orange']
plt.plot(pd.Series(s).value_counts(), linestyle = '-')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.xlabel('Fruit')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How could I rotate the labels in order to visualise all of them? I would be interested in visualising all the names on the x-axis

Answer (score 0):

For the rotation of the x axis, you should try :

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Comment: You should either edit your precious answer or comment on his quesion rather than post this as a new question.

Comment: You are coorect, that was my mistake, sorry .